# Covering index in Postgres 12

Tags: postgresql, optimization, indexing

My table has 5500000 test records (Postgres 12).
I have an uncertainty because of big costs when I'm using a covering index on my tables.

So, I create index:

```
create index concurrently idx_log_type
    on logs (log_type)
    include (log_body);
```

After I execute a request:

```
explain (analyze)
select log_body
from logs where log_type = 1
limit 100;
```

I have getting a result:

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..5.05 rows=100 width=33) (actual time=0.118..0.138 rows=100 loops=1)
    - ->  Index Only Scan using idx_log_type on logs  (cost=0.43..125736.10 rows=2720667 width=33) (actual time=0.107..0.118 rows=100 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (log_type = 1)
        Heap Fetches: 0
Planning Time: 0.558 ms
Execution Time: 0.228 ms
```

At first glance, this is so good, but the cost range is very large.
Is this normal or should you optimize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's an artifact of `EXPLAIN`: it shows the cost for the complete index scan, just as if there were no `LIMIT`. But the whole plan is priced correctly.

So you can ignore the high upper cost limit on the index scan.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that. I've seen it before and was unsure about the upper value of the cost.

Comment: @laurenz-albe, Thank you for an explantory comment